# Automatically Hide/Unhide rows - questionnaire

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Hi I need some help with my work sheet. I have to build a dynamic questionnaire and I need to have a code that allow me to hide/ Unhide automatically some rows base on a cell information. Example:

if c6 is "internally" then show me row 7 but hide 8 to 107

if c6 is "Externally" then hide all the rows from 7 to 107

if c7 is "yes" then show me row 8 but hide 9 to 107

if c7 is "No" then show me row 8 but hide 9 to 107

if c8 is "Critical" then show me row 9 but hide 10 to 107

if c8 is "Important" show me row 9 but hide 10 to 107

if c8 is "Ordinary" show me row 9 but hide 10 to 107

if c8 is "Other" then show me row 9 but hide 10 to 107

if c9 is "Critical" then show me row 10 but hide 11 to 107

if c9 is "Important" then show me row 10 but hide 11 to 107

if c9 is "Ordinary" then show me row 10 but hide 11 to 107

if c9 is "Other" then show me row 10 but hide 11 to 107

etc.

can somebody help me?

Comment: Is this for Excel, OpenOffice Calc, LibreOffice Calc, or some other spreadsheet app? Please advise.

Comment: Hi Deni, please correct your message with "then" instead of "than" and read your message again as there are some duplicates within your example sentences, making them painful to read.

Comment: Hi is for Excel

Comment: Thank you modified

Comment: What have you already tried in VBA?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$6" Then
Call HideRow1
End If
End Sub


Sub HideRow1()
If Range("C6").Value = "Externally" Then
Rows("7:107").Activate
Rows("7:107").EntireRow.Hidden = "True"
ElseIf Range("C6").Value = "Internally" Then
Rows(7).Activate
Rows(7).EntireRow.Hidden = "False"




End If
End Sub

Comment: Before you go to down this rabbit hole, have you looked at Sharepoint's survey functionality [or qualtrics](https://www.qualtrics.com/core-xm/survey-software/)  free account may be enough

Comment: The answer to the only question asked in this question ("can somebody help me?") is: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends upon what you mean by "hide row X to 107."

If you mean literally `Hide` the rows so that row 108 is the next numbered row people can see, then you must use VBA because no worksheet function can control that aspect of formatting.

If you mean "have a long empty white space" or if you mean "suppress the ordinary content of those cells, causing, say, rows 11 to 107 not to act upon the formulas they would have acted upon, and cause the formulas that would have been active in rows 108+ to begin showing results in, say, rows 11-onward" then you CAN do it. Each of those takes a different approach.

I will describe the general idea since you really have not given any detail to work with, but you'll get the idea easily.

First, those conditions. They actually belong in the following order, slightly restated:

1. if c6 is "Externally" then hide all the rows from 7 to 107
2. if c6 is "Internally" then show me row 7
3. if c7 is "Yes" or “No” then show me row 8
4. if c8 is "Critical" or “Important” or “Ordinary” or “Other” then show me row 9
5. if c9 is "Critical" or “Important” or “Ordinary” or “Other” then show me row 10 but hide 11 to 107

In ALL cases, rows 11-107 get "hidden." As for the others, if c6 has "Externally" all the rest are hidden, but then you change tack a bit and show each row IFF one or more conditions are true, hiding following rows if false. So, f using VBA, just do simple tests, in the order above, causing the macro to end when a test fails. Easiest done if you hide all rows 7-107 first, then do the tests and unhiding a row at a time if a test succeeds or exiting if one fails.

If you wish to simply suppress the material in those rows, not actually `HIDE` them, you would use Conditional Formatting. Start with the first test, using "$C$6" not "C6" and choose to use a formula for the test with the formula being something like:

```
=$C$66="Externally"
```

(The "IF" aspect of it is implied.)

and format for the text color to be "White" (or whatever background color and fill you have if not White and no fill). The cells to apply it to if successful would be all the applicable cells in rows 7-107. Be sure to check "Stop if True".

Continue on, using `OR()` for those with multiple acceptable results but since they cause the next row to be shown, not suppressed, make the cells the rule applies to start one row lower than the first one:  the first one was testing C6, and suppressing rows starting immediately with the next one, 7, but these should start one lower, so if testing C7, they'd start suppressing not row 8 and onward, but rather row 9 and onward.

Well, that would seem to be the idea, but it is slightly more complicated. You must really make the first rule the one that tests C9, not C6, and work backwards. So your first rule tests the last condition, the second rule tests the second-to-last condition and on "upwards." Otherwise, all the rows from 7-onward would be suppressed. Odd, isn't it, the backwards feeling way you must think of these things?

If you wish to suppress all the applicable rows, but want the material that would be in row 108 showing up immediately (no huge empty white space!), then you have to do it IN the formulas.

The idea then would be to make formulas that test the condition. They are testing facts in the row above, so row 7, cell A7 perhaps, would test C6 for "Externally" and either branch to further formula that would have been the full formula otherwise in that cell, A7 for example, OR branch to the formula that would have been in cell A108 in this example. You would continue that idea through row 10, but rows 11-107 would have simple branching with no testing of the C column cells.

That's the tricky part. If row 7 fails and row 8 should start row 108's material, cool. But what if it succeeded and row 8 should have started row 108's material? You have to have the formulas for that material (row 108-onwards) all be relative using `OFFSET()`, etc. (There are several ways.)

Other ways exist. For instance, a "helper sheet" (not column like usual) on which ALL the material is present, no testing or hiding, and on this sheet you choose where to start pulling results from the helper sheet. That would GREATLY simplify the difficulty and complexity, but for some reason people hate even helper columns that are temporary, so most will probably scorn a whole helper sheet.

But these last two things don't fit perfectly, not logically. Why say "hidden" if you mean "suppressed" but people DO speak inaccurately since they know exactly what they mean and do not realize they are confusing the issues to others. But more logically, who would want a huge empty space? So that seems unlikely. And that 100 rows or so from 11 to 107 that are always hidden, presumably they have important material? If not, what are they in existence for at all? So it seems likeliest you need the VBA approach. If so, now that the things you want to accomplish are in proper order with excess material that was meaningless to their purposes excised, and a basic approach laid out for the macro, the macro might be very much easier to write. Those conditions have to be in a proper order, like a flow chart, if you'll excuse a tool from the 1980's being referenced, rather than a hodgepodge jumping about, mostly in order, but not nearly enough. That's a true thing for any approach that involves actual programming language programming, or even function/formula programming. It's harder than the actual writing which flows nicely once the path is laid out.